# A group of 8 men and 16 women are partitioned into 8 committees of 4 people each. What is the probability that there is a man in each committee?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Can someone explain and give an answer for this question?
A group of 8 men and 16 women are partitioned into 8 committees
of 3 people each. What is the probability that there is a man in each committee?

Comment: How do you partition $24$ people in $8$ groups of $4$?  Did you mean $3$ people each?

Comment: Sorry yeah I meant 3 people in each

Comment: Ok.  What have you tried?  Have you, for example, calculated the total number of ways to form these committees?

Comment: Yes I have. An answer that I have right now is (8C1)(16C2)*(7C1)(14C2)*...*(1C1)(2C2). But I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: No...you seem to be trying to put one man on each.  I'm looking for the total, with no such constraint.

Comment: The total would be 24C3

Comment: Oh, no.  That's the way to form a single committee.  To form $8$ committees you need to start with one, $\binom {24}3$ as you wrote, then make another, so multiply by $\binom {21}3$, and so on.  Now, presumably you don't care about the order of the committees so in the end you have to divide by $8!$ to take care of the symmetry.

Comment: How would this take care of there being a man in each committee?

Comment: you did that correctly in your earlier comment ... (8C1)(16C2)*(7C1)(14C2)*...*(1C1)(2C2)

Comment: It wouldn't.  You have to go step by step here.  First you need to count the total.  Then you need to count the ones that satisfy the constraint,  Then you divide.  Don't try to do it all in one step.

Comment: @WW1  You have to watch out for the symmetry.  If you do the count this way, then you must divide by $8!$ in the end.  If the order of the committees mattered, then this expression would be correct, but for mine you'd have to remove the $8!$.

Comment: Could one of you post a complete answer at the bottom?

Comment: I've posted something but you should work on it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the order of the committees does not matter (it's the same either way, but we need the calculations to line up).

Total:  The total number of ways to form the committees is $$\frac 1{8!}\times \prod_{n=0}^7 \binom {24-3n}3$$

Where the $8!$ reflects the the fact that the order of the committees is irrelevant.

Constrained:  Now to count the number of arrangements that pass the constraint.  To do that list the men.  Now form $8$ committees of two women each and put them next to the men.  Doing it this way, the order of the two women committees does matter because we are pairing them with the ordered men.  Thus there are $$\prod_{n=0}^7 \binom {16-2n}2$$  ways to choose the committees such that each has a man on it.  We want the quotient, which we compute with mechanical assistance.  Barring error the answer comes to $\boxed {0.008920814}$

Comment: Yep! Masterful combinatorics. Guess there's no error.  (+1) Simulation of 10 million iterations gave 0.00894, of which maybe three or four places are accurate. // With 12 men & 12 women the probability jumps to about 0.313.